# Why can't I log a state to the console in componentWillMount but can in componentDidMount?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

In my React-Rails app, I am confused why I cannot log a state to the console in componentWillMount but can do so in componentDidMount.

Below is my code:

```
componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({ records: this.props.data });
    console.log(this.state.records); // throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'records' of null
}
componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.state.records); // returns records array
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

So in other words, `this.state` is not defined during `componentWillMount` and using `setState()` does not cause it to be defined. Once you get to `componentDidMount` then `this.state` is defined with the values you set.